# maven surefire plugin - specifying a single test - does NOT run

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have this maven profile setup.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>com.something.test.X.java</include>
        </includes>

        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>reporter</name>
                <value>org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>                          
                <value>Listener</value>
            </property>
        </properties>

        <systemProperties>
            <property>
                <name>x.host</name>
                <value>${server.ip}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>http_port</name>
                <value>${http_port}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>https_port</name>
                <value>${https_port}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>jmx_remote_port</name>
                <value>${jmx_remote_port}</value>
            </property>
        </systemProperties>

        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <x.host>${server.ip}</x.host>
            <env.BUILD_NUMBER>${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</env.BUILD_NUMBER>
            <env.HOSTNAME>${env.HOSTNAME}</env.HOSTNAME>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When i run the profile, the test included does not run!
What am i doing wrong? i even tried it with the suitexmlfile but i get a parsing error where it cannot find the class.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help (cannot test it myself now), but can you try to specify only class name instead of full class name (with package) in `include` section.

Comment: I did try that. It doesn't work. I basically want to run one of the integration tests instead of all. I've tried using <groups>, <excludegroups>, <suitexml>, -Dtest.... i am out of ideas now:(

Comment: Ah, I see now. Remove `.java` in the end of the test name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrew Logvinov suggested, you should remove `.java` from the name of the test you include. In general, test coordinates are specified as `<class-name>[#<method-name>]`.